# Is this code a Circular linkedlist

Tags: c, data-structures, circular-list

The following code was been given from our school as a sample for circular linkedlist and told  each student to build a own version of circular linkedlist.

My question is, is the following code really a circular linkedlist?

```
// Program of circular linked list
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *link;
}*last;

main()
{
    int choice,n,m,po,i;
    last=NULL;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("1.Create List\n");
        printf("2.Add at begining\n");
        printf("3.Add after \n");
        printf("4.Delete\n");
        printf("5.Display\n");
        printf("6.Quit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
         case 1:
            printf("How many nodes you want : ");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            for(i=0; i < n;i++)
            {
                printf("Enter the element : ");
                scanf("%d",&m);
                create_list(m);
            }
            break;
         case 2:
            printf("Enter the element : ");
            scanf("%d",&m);
            addatbeg(m);
            break;
         case 3:
            printf("Enter the element : ");
            scanf("%d",&m);
            printf("Enter the position after which this element is inserted : ");
            scanf("%d",&po);
            addafter(m,po);
            break;
         case 4:
            if(last == NULL)
            {
                printf("List underflow\n");
                continue;
            }
            printf("Enter the number for deletion : ");
            scanf("%d",&m);
            del(m);
            break;
         case 5:
            display();
            break;
         case 6:
            exit(0);
         default:
            printf("Wrong choice\n");
        }/*End of switch*/
    }/*End of while*/
}/*End of main()*/

create_list(int num)
{
    struct node *q,*tmp;
    tmp= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tmp->info = num;

    if(last == NULL)
    {
        last = tmp;
        tmp->link = last;
    }
    else
    {
        tmp->link = last->link; /*added at the end of list*/
        last->link = tmp;
        last = tmp;
    }
}/*End of create_list()*/

addatbeg(int num)
{
    struct node *tmp;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tmp->info = num;
    tmp->link = last->link;
    last->link = tmp;
}/*End of addatbeg()*/

addafter(int num,int pos)
{

    struct node *tmp,*q;
    int i;
    q = last->link;
    for(i=0; i < pos-1; i++)
    {
        q = q->link;
        if(q == last->link)
        {
            printf("There are less than %d elements\n",pos);
            return;
        }
    }/*End of for*/
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node) );
    tmp->link = q->link;
    tmp->info = num;
    q->link = tmp;
    if(q==last)    /*Element inserted at the end*/
        last=tmp;
}/*End of addafter()*/

del(int num)
{
    struct node *tmp,*q;
    if( last->link == last && last->info == num)  /*Only one element*/
    {
        tmp = last;
        last = NULL;
        free(tmp);
        return;
    }
    q = last->link;
    if(q->info == num)
    {
        tmp = q;
        last->link = q->link;
        free(tmp);
        return;
    }
    while(q->link != last)
    {
        if(q->link->info == num)     /*Element deleted in between*/
        {
            tmp = q->link;
            q->link = tmp->link;
            free(tmp);
            printf("%d deleted\n",num);
            return;
        }
        q = q->link;
    }/*End of while*/
    if(q->link->info == num)    /*Last element deleted q->link=last*/
    {
        tmp = q->link;
        q->link = last->link;
        free(tmp);
        last = q;
        return;
    }
    printf("Element %d not found\n",num);
}/*End of del()*/

display()
{
    struct node *q;
    if(last == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    q = last->link;
    printf("List is :\n");
    while(q != last)
    {
        printf("%d ", q->info);
        q = q->link;
    }
    printf("%d\n",last->info);
}/*End of display()*/
```

The reason why I am not agreeing is because `NULL` is used to check the last node in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the code implements a [circular linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

The variable last is only NULL at the beginning, after adding the first element lasts link will point to itself. See function createlist.

Non circular lists always have the last elements next pointer set to NULL to indicate the end of the list.

Edit:
Sorry I can't do ascii art with my ipad.

```
Start:
last=NULL

call createlist( 12 )
Result: Last(12) -> Last

call addatbeg( 15 )

Result:
tmp( 15 ) -> Last( 12 -)
 ^                 |
 |                 |
 +----<-------<----+
```

To understand how these pointers work I would recommend to draw a simple diagramm
based on the instructions in the code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, definitely circular. The point where its most obvious is in `addafter` where it checks for `if(q == last->link)` instead of `if(q == NULL)` to detect if it has run out of list items.

Comment: @torak & @stacker: what will the value of (tmp->link = last->link)  in function addatbeg, is it pointing the first node in the list ?

Also what will q point to in (q = last->link),bit confused explanation needed ...

Comment: @Tuhin I will edit the post later it's not possible right now

Answer (score 0):

I didn't scrutinize in great detail, but it looks like it is indeed a linked list.  As for a *circular linked list*, I haven't come across that before.

The check for NULL is testing whether the node has a *next* node.  If it doesn't (NULL), then it is the last node.

Comment: A *circular linked list* is a normal linked list where there's no *last* node, or "last node points back to first node", so to speak. You just hold a pointer to *any* node in the list and iterate until you are back where you started.

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov: Yes exactly !
But here in this list the last node should always point to head instead it is checked that weather the last node is NULL or not.

I hope you can understand  what i mean.
in circular list there is no point of using a NULL...
I think the above code is a plain  singly linkedlist or rather modifies singly linked list

Comment: @Tuhin, when the list is empty, your pointer is `NULL`, so you have to check for it.